# How to remove border in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following webiste. www.theprinterdepo.com
On the top, I have a sliding text, made with a component called EasySlide for Magento.

I created the outter border in red, but I cant seem be able to remove the inner gray border.

The html code for the outter thing is:

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>READ WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY ABOUT US</strong></span></p>
<table style="width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid #fc1102;" colspan="2">
<p style="text-align: center;">{{block type="firstslider/firstslider" name="firstslider" categoryid="8" sliderid="4" topbuttons="0" bottombuttons="0" style="width:945px;height: 30px;" duration="3" frequency="10" autoglide="true"}}</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

The code for each slide is like:

```
<p>I ordered a HP printer and received it the next day. Excellent service and I will order again.</p>
```

My guess is that this third party pluggin is adding the border somewhere, but I should be able to override this gray annoying border and remove it.

Comment: You've a border on `div.scroller` in `slider.css`

Comment: hahha, shame on all you -1'ers without a valid comment, and answer is here! loooool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css find "div.scroller" in "slider.css"

where

```
border: 1px solid #cccccc
```

is written, just remove it

Answer (score 1):

The div with the border has a class scroller, something like this in your css will remove it

```
div.scroller {
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You may have to make your css more specified (see http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) to get your style to override the plugins